# Metadata fields required for debian Release files?

Tags: debian, apt

Which of these fields are required for a `Release` APT file?

```
Origin
Label
Suite
Codename
Architectures
Components
Description
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Debian Wiki page on Repository Format](https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat#A.22Release.22_files):

> - These fields are optional. They may be displayed to the user by
>     package management tool or used for pinning. It is suggested that any
>     repository published for other users to use fills meaningful
>     information in these fields so that the user can tell apart different
>     repositories.
>
>   - Description
>   - Origin
>   - Label
>   - Version
>   - Suite
>   - Codename
>
>   In Debian repositories the indices are stored in a directory named
>     after Suite or Codename (actually one is symlinked to the other). The
>     Release file may specify other location, though.
> - These fields determine layout of the repository and should contain 
>     something meaningful to the user. In Debian these fields may contain
>     lowercase characters, numbers, `-` and `_`. Other characters (e.g.,
>     uppercase letters) should also work but these fields are used for file
>     paths so use of special characters that might need special treatment
>     in URIs or filesystem is discouraged.
>
>   - Components
>   - Architectures
> - These fields are purely functional and used mostly internally by
>     packaging tools.
>
>   - Date
>   - Valid-Until
>   - MD5Sum, SHA1, SHA256
>   - NotAutomatic and ButAutomaticUpgrades

The necessary fields are:

- Components
- Architectures

These are sufficient for [flat layouts](https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat#Flat_Repository_Format) (`deb http://example.org path/`) For official style archives (`deb http://example.org stable main`), an additional field is required:

- Codename

Comment: Oh wait! Without the codename tag, we get one error with `apt-get update`. So I think, that also the codename tag is required.

Comment: @ncomputers.org interesting. What's the error? It's possible the `sources.list` entry you used relies on a codename.

Comment: Conflicting distribution: http://ncomputers.org wheezy Relase (expected wheezy but got '')

Comment: And the `sources.list` entry you used?

Comment: deb http://ncomputers.org/debian wheezy main

Comment: @ncomputers.org The `wheezy` in that line is the component. If you'd used [a flat layout](https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat#Flat_Repository_Format) as described later on in the same wiki page, the component is unnecessary.